# Trying to modify the type of a field with .WithDefaultValue()

Tags: fluent-migrator

I have a table with a column that has a default value:

```
this.Create.Table("msgqueue")
    .WithColumn("id")
        .AsInt32()
        .Identity()
        .PrimaryKey()
    .WithColumn("queueddt")
        .AsDateTime()
        .Nullable()
        .WithDefaultValue(SystemMethods.CurrentDateTime)
;
```

I want to change this from datetime to datetime2:

```
this.Alter.Table("msgqueue")
    .AlterColumn("queueddt")
        .AsCustom("datetime2")
        .Nullable()
        .WithDefaultValue(SystemMethods.CurrentDateTime)
;
```

This gives me errors:

```
The error was The object 'DF_msgqueue_queueddt' is dependent on column 'queueddt'.
```

I did some googling around, and discovered Delete.DefaultConstraint(), so I tried that, first:

```
this.Delete.DefaultConstraint()
    .OnTable("msgqueue")
    .OnColumn("msgqueue")
;
```

And I still see the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before your Alter Table statement try dropping the default constraint using Execute.Sql:

```
Execute.Sql(@"ALTER TABLE msgqueue DROP CONSTRAINT DF_msgqueue_queueddt")
```

Also, your column name is wrong in your last statement. It should be:

```
this.Delete.DefaultConstraint()
.OnTable("msgqueue")
.OnColumn("queueddt");
```